# update two join table in one statement

Tags: sql

I have a problem. I have a 2 table which is `table orders` and `table delivery`. table order has column `order_recieved`. by default `NULL`. and table delivery has column `delivery_status` with value `order shipped`. now, if customer click a button to update `order_received`, the column will change `NULL` value to `Recieved` value. and my problem is how column `delivery_status` will also change to `order shipped` value to `complete` value? the PK table `orders` is `order_no` and FK table `delivery` is `orderFK`.
Can someone help me how to update the value?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: you'll need to issue two separate update statements for two different tables. no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update one table per update statement. I'd recommend sticking them both in the same stored procedure so that you can make one database call and have both values updated.